# Number of agglomerate sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to [this](https://ciencias.uniandes.edu.co/es/publicaciones/matematica-estructural) book I'm reading, a set is  said to be agglomerate if:

> Let $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$, and $A_{3}$  be any sets. Given a set $X$ we say
> that $X$ is agglomerate if for every selection of $i$, $j$ and $k$
> between $1$ and $3$ (in other words $\{1, 2, 3\} = \{i, j, k\}$) we
> have:
>
> (i)$\emptyset \subseteq X \subseteq A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}$
>
> (ii) If $X \cap A_{i} \not= \emptyset$ then $X \supseteq A_{i} \backslash (A_{j} \cup A_{k})$
>
> (iii) If $X \cap A_{i} \not= \emptyset$ and $X \cap A_{j} \not= \emptyset$ then $X \supseteq (A_{i} \cap A_{j}) \backslash A_{k}$
>
> (iv) If $X \cap A_{i} \not= \emptyset$ and $X \cap A_{j} \not= \emptyset$ and $X \cap A_{k} \not= \emptyset$ then $X \supseteq A_{i} \cap A_{j} \cap A_{k}$

The question is then, given sets $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$ and $A_{3}$, how many agglomerate sets exists?

Comment: Why don't you try every possibility for I,j,k. I think there are only 7 of them.

Comment: @Porky I think the are at most 8 agglomerate sets. The reason being   that if an agglomerate set shares one element with some $A_{i}$ then it must contain $A_{i} \backslash (A_{j} \cup A_{k}) $ and if it shares no more elements with any other set then it must be equal to $A_{i} \backslash (A_{j} \cup A_{k}) $- There are 8 ways to choose from which $A_{i}$ will the agglomerate set share elements with, and each determines exactly one agglomerate set, thus  the answer should be 8. What do you think?